# PHP - file_get_contents is taking forever and fails

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this ZF controller which is a very basic DB query and reading the user status as true or false. If i use in browser the direct URL it works instantly.

Server 1:

```
  public function getstatusAction() {
    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');       
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();   
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getQuery();
    //$data = (object) $post;
    $this->db = Application_Model_Db::db_load();

    $sql = "select id from users where
              status='online'
        limit 1";
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);

    $json = '';
    if (count($result) > 0) {
      $json = array(
          'result' =>true,
      );      
    }   else {
      $json = array(
          'result' =>false,
      );        
    } 


    $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($json))
            ->sendResponse();

    exit;
  }
```

But when i from Server 2 reading that url using following, its taking forever and not even getting success

```
$section = file_get_contents("http://server1.domain.com/ajax/getstatus");
```

How can i fix it? (also do not see any error logs)

Comment: From server2, when i do ping server1.domain.com i do not get any reply.

Comment: You cannot get a verbose output for HTTP requests with file_get_contents, but you can with CURL. Google curl verbose php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is set to "1" on the server2.

Alternatively you can use this function:

```
function get_content($URL){
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
  }
```

Comment: file_get_contents would return false immediately and raise warnings stating that there's no suitable wrapper available if allow_url_fopen is set to 0.